# Connecting a form to a Javascript Object (and other best practice advice)

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, forms, observer-pattern

I've been using javascript to do lightweight functionality on sites for years - DOM manipulation etc - but just now im beginning to investigate using it to do a lot more of the heavy lifting (in combo with PHP). I've only just started getting into OO JS, and im still trying to get my head around the best-practices and design patterns that work well with it.

To be more specific - my question is, can anyone here suggest techniques for connecting a form to a javascript object?

In my current implementation I have an JS object that can be edited by a (fairly large) form. When I instantiate the object I attach an onchange observer to the form, whose callback syncs the form fields with the object parameters. I'm handling the form submitting through AJAX - there is also a periodic request that saves a temporary version of the form info to a mySQL DB. One thing I wonder is whether it is possible to easily handle syncing in the other direction - onchange of the object the form fields update (on form reset for instance).

I am interested to know if this approach is a correct/sensible one, and more generally I would be very interested to hear advice with regard to OOJS form handling.

Cheers in advance :)

(Im using Prototype btw)

Comment: You've had 24 people look at this in the last hour, with no takers. I would suggest you rephrase the question. What you're asking for is not that specific or clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$("form").serialize(true);`

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/serialize

You dont need the onchange event, you can just call the serialize() method every time you need to get the form data.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a method in you object that resyncs the object with the form? And call that on every change of the object? You could create a special change function to assure that it gets called on every change.

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfectly reasonable approach. JS doesn't entirely encourage this sort of thing due to its curious object system and in particular the way bound methods are not first-class objects, but with a bit of suitable metaclass and callback glue it's eminently possible.

You might also want to look at a widget library if you'd like to get more of this kind of low-level form handling stuff for free. Haven't tried the ones built on top of Prototype; other possibilities include YUI's one.

Updating the model from the server can be pretty simple. Generally you'd poll an AJAX request and have the server pass back either diffs, if it knows them, or else just timestamp each object update, send the new object details to the client side on each update, and have the client decide how to merge that with any changes the user has made in the meantime.